# Let the GPU handle recursive algorithm

Tags: objective-c, gpu

I have a complex recursive algorithm that in it's php implementation runs about 15 minutes in the CLI to complete. I was thinking about porting it to objective-c and wanted to know who I can make use of the the GPU for the calculations. Is there a way to designate threads to be executed by the GPU?

Thanks

Comment: Not in the standard Objective-C runtime.  You'd have to use a GPU-specific API which will probably be implemented in C or C++ (which are usable from Objective-C).  Why do you want to do it in Objective-C anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use the GPU for calculations, although depending on the task it may not be advantageous. Without posting code it's anyone's guess what the most efficient means for your implementation might be. I would recommend reading the "[**Concurrency Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide.pdf)", for it's an excellent starting point in terms understanding the appropriate ways one might want to handle concurrent threading within Objective-C.